# Bing Health & Fitness doesn't work in the background

Tags: 8.0, location-services, background-tasks

I have really big problem with the Bing Health & Fitness app. When my screen turns off, it stops tracking me. When the screen is on it works fine. My lock screen is set to 1 minute, after that the screen turns off. When I turn the screen on again, it just draws a straight line between my last position (when screen was on), and the current position.

The app is allowed to work in background, the live tile works, battery saver is turned off. I have tried reinstalling the app, restarting the phone, doing a soft reset, as well as disabling the app from working in background and allowing it again, but nothing works. Also I've disabled many other apps from working in background.

Has anyone had the same problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Bing Health & Fitness is pretty new so there are many bugs to fix.

*Try [Endomondo](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=6cd31275-c5dd-df11-a844-00237de2db9e) instead if you really need the functionality.*